# How to remove blob, clob columns from couchbase tables?

Tags: couchbase

I have a use-case to process random rows from couchbase tables. I'm required to remove the blob/clob columns from the results to further process.
I'm very new to couchbase. Followed the documentation.
I've set up a test cluster on the couchbase server. And I've manually setup blob data in document.

```
{
  "experience": 14248,
  "hitpoints": 9223372036854775807,
  "jsonType": "player",
  "level": 141,
  "loggedIn": true,
  "name": "Aaron1",
  "uuid": "78edf902-7dd2-49a4-99b4-1c94ee286a33",
  "image": {
    "@type": "blob",
    "content_type": "image/jpeg",
    "digest": "sha1–4xlj1AKFgLdzcD7a1pVChrVTJIc=",
    "length": 3888349
  }
}
```

I have the following questions:

1. Couchbase has blob datatype. I'm not seeing any good documentation with examples for Clob datatype. Does couchbase support clob datatype? if yes, could you provide me a sample dataset as an example.
2. While filtering out the blob datatype columns through my utility, I'm looking for fields having "@type" and "content_type" attribute. Is this approach correct? Or I'm in the risk of missing any blob type of column?

Could anyone pls help me with the understanding or route me to the right documentation for this purpose.

Comment: Perhaps you could explain what you mean by cblob.  As far as I know, that is an Oracle datatype.  If you would explain, in the question, why you want a cblob instead of a blob, it would be easier to help you.

Comment: we do have those datatypes in Couchbase as well.
Ref: https://blog.couchbase.com/couchbase-for-oracle-developers-part-4-data-types/

While I'm able to find examples for blob datatype in couchbase. I'm not able to fine any for clob but the documentation suggests that even clob exists for couchbase.

For my usecase, there is no blob/clob preference. My usecase is simply to process the couchbase tables and remove any columns with large object datatypes (clob/blob).

Comment: Couchbase supports a Blob type.  It does not support a Clob type.  You can find Blobs by looking for documents that have contents whose @type is "blob"

Comment: I regret to say that this comment is completely wrong.  I misunderstood the question.  I work with the Couchbase Lite team.  Couchbase Lite does not support a CBlob type.  Couchbase, however, does.  I beg your pardon.